# Stuck trying to add an Event Handler to a late bound object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binding, delegates

I am stuck trying to handle an event raised by a Late Bound Object.

I got as far as Loading the assembly (sLibFile contains the location of the Library):

```
moAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(sLibFile)
```

Getting the type of object I'm creating is no problem

```
moType = moAssembly.GetType("Some.Object")
```

And creating the object is a doddle....

```
moObject = Activator.CreateInstance(moType)
```

But then I'm stuck. The object I have instantiated exposes an event "GetField" with the following signature:

```
Event GetField(FieldName As String, nPageNumber As Integer, ByRef sValue As String)
```

I wrote a sub to deal with this, but .... how do I add this Sub as the Handler for this event? AddHandler only works with early bound objects.

I can get the Event alright.....

```
oEvent = moType.GetEvent("GetField")
```

or perhaps

```
oEvent = moObject.GetType().GetEvent("GetField")
```

But after that I'm stuck.... How do I then link that to the Sub I wrote (I named the Sub moObject_GetField)?

```
oEvent.AddEventHandler(moObject, AddressOf moObject_GetField)
```

This raises the error "'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to '[Delegate]' because type '[Delegate]' is declared 'MustInherit' and cannot be created."

Now what?

Comment: see: [EventInfo.AddEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn I already found that link but I don't understand how to translate what it says in there to fit my situation. As you can see I already tried to use .AddEventHandler but it doesn't like me using AddressOf ... so what do I do to get over that?

Comment: So my question is.... Given I have written a Sub moObject_GetField(FieldName As String, nPageNumber As Integer, ByRef sValue As String) - What do I do with that Sub in order to allow it to deal with oEvent? I can't simply use it in an AddressOf ... So I think I have to create a Delegate, but that's where I am sorely lacking in knowledge. Please help me fill in the blanks here :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't read through your question thoroughly. Read through the first 5 steps of [How to: Hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-hook-up-a-delegate-using-reflection). That will show you how to create the delegate that you can pass to EventInfo.AddEventHandler.